# A problem of nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ and $n\geq 1$. Assume that $T \in L(U)$ is nilpotent of degree $n$.
Show that there are $T$-cyclic vectors $u_1, . . . , u_n$ in $U$ of respective periods $1, . . . , n.$

I know that If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $T$ a nilpotent operator with index of nilpotence equal to dim $V$, then $T$ is cyclic.

I am solving book exercise what I need to do here I don't understand. Kindly give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: As the degree of $T$ is exactly the dimension of $U$, we must have $\dim \text{Ker}\, T^j = j$ for all $j=1,2,\dots,n$. Pick $u_j\in \text{Ker}\, T^{n-j}$ such that $u_j\notin \text{Ker}\, T^{n-j-1}$ and we get the result.

Comment: My previous answer is wrong, because it's not enough if $u_j\in \text{Ker}\, T^{n-j}$ only. Actually, for nilpotent operators with degree exactly the dimension of vector space, we have $V_1\subset V_2\subset\dotsb\subset V_{n}$, where $V_j\,\hat{=}\,\text{Ker}\, T^{j}$ and $\dim V_j = j$.